# How to remove node server from Visual Studio Solution

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio

I am learning AngularJS by following Pro AngularJS book.

As per the instructions given in the book, downloaded and installed `nodejs` and created `SportsStoreServer.js` file within nodejs installation folder. Hence, I need to start this server to be able to work with my Visual studio project.

But, after some days; now, I am thinking to use Visual Studio Development Server only instead of running nodejs server separately to be able to run my Visual Studio solution. But, I am not understanding how to uninstall nodejs server.

What I want to do is, I should be able to run my Visual Studio project by just pressing F5. I don't what `Node` involvement in the middle.

When I verified in Google, all the available resources were talking about how to uninstall nodejs from System. But, I am unable to get the solution for running my Project inside Visual Studio solution.

Can anybody please suggest me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need [Node Tools for VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/node-js-vs.aspx) . Here is a [getting started guide](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/g_arora/getting-started-with-node-js-tools-for-visual-studio/) -

Comment: I could not deduce anything useful information for my problem. Of-course, article is nice.

Comment: <<I am unable to get the solution for running my Project inside Visual Studio solution.>> Doesn't that article answer this part of your question?